# Multiple CPPickerView in a class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I am using CPPickerviewDemo class to show custom circular picker view. I have to show 15 circular pickers in my view. So in spite of creating 15 CPPickerview objects I tried to use xib and link datasource delegate in storyboard itself. But unfortunately delegate and datasource methods not getting called.

So creating 15 objects is the only option? Somebody help me out on this.

Comment: how you are using nib to create 15 CPPickerView Object..

Comment: By adding uiviews and changing class name to CPPickerview (similar to custom tableviewcell)